# Symmetric matrix as sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $B$ be a symmetric matrix, and $A$ an invertible matrix (or course both square matrices with the same order). Show that there is a matrix $X$ such that $$B= AX^T + A^T X$$

Comment: As sranthrop points out in the answer below, the statement does not hold in general. I guess there may be a typo in your question --- the correct statement is probably that $B=AX^T+XA^T$ for some $X$. If this is the case, the statement is rather trivial and it holds over any field of characteristic $\ne2$.

Comment: You're right! There must be a typo in the lecture notes I'm reading... . But just to finish the question, how can I solve for $X$ in $B= AT^T + XA^T$? I can guess that $X=\frac{1}{2}B(A^T)^{-1}$, but I am not able to write the complete proof:  multiplying by $(A^T)^{-1}$ we have then $B(A^T)^{-1}=AX^T(A^T)^{-1}+X =A(A^{-1}X)^T+X$, but I get stuck there! BecauseI don't know that $A^{-1}X$ is symmetric do I?

Comment: Note that $AX^T+XA^T=(AX^T)+(AX^T)^T$. Since $B$ is symmetric, we have that $B=1/2B+1/2B^T$. Thus, if $AX^T=1/2B$, you are done. Indeed, take $X=1/2(A^{-1}B)^T=1/2 B(A^{-1})^T$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**JUST A COMMENT:** Are you sure you didn't miss any additional assumptions?

I think this is not possible in general. For instance, take $A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Writing $X=\begin{pmatrix}x_1 & x_2 \\ x_3 & x_4 \end{pmatrix}$, your equation is equivalent to the linear system
\begin{align*}
x_2-x_3&=1\\
x_2-x_3&=0,
\end{align*}
which obviously has no solution.

In general, if $A$ is symmetric, but $A^{-1}B$ is not (see the example above), then your equation cannot have a solution: If $A$ is symmetric, then $B=AX^T+A^TX=A(X^T+X)$, and this implies $X^T+X=A^{-1}B$. The left hand side is symmetric, but the right hand side is not.

Comment: There was a typo in the lectures notes I was reading. But the statement was that and you gave a very convincing counterexample. Thanks!